# How to input multiple audio devices on seperate audio tracks

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg exe and I want to record two seperate audio devices (in this case, 'virtual-audio-capturer' & 'Microphone (USB PnP Sound Device)').

If possible I would also like to record the two audio devices to seperate audio tracks in the video.

I tried just adding another audio device on the end, but in this case it would only record the last added audio device:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer":audio="Microphone (USB PnP Sound Device)" <final-path>
```

How can I record the multiple audio devices on seperate audo tracks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dshow device only accepts one device of each type (video/audio). So, you'll have to ingest the 2nd audio using another input instance and then map both streams.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer":audio="Microphone (USB PnP Sound Device)" -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (USB PnP Sound Device)" -map 0 -map 1 <final-path>
```